# C add strtok to char*

Tags: c, strtok

I'm having a problem when using `strtok` and I don't know if the problem is on `strtok` or something else.

I have a .txt file with data like this:

```
sometextdada;othertextdata
yetmoredata;andmoredata
```

The read data is to store in an `struct` defined this way:

```
typedef struct team{
    char *name;
    char *teamPlace;
}Team;
```

If I do this:

```
char buffer[100];
Team eq;
/*Read first line*/
fgets(buffer, 100, equipas)!= NULL);
eq.name= strtok(buffer,";\n");
eq.teamPlace= strtok (NULL,";\n");

printf("%s %s\n", eq.name,eq.teamPlace);
```

I can see that `strtok` is working as expected and storing `sometextdada` in `eq.name` and `othertextdata` in `eq.teamPlace`

Now I want to replace that `printf` with a function that adds `eq` to a linked list that's defined this way:

```
typedef struct nodeTeam{
    int numberOfTeams;
    Team team;
    struct nodeTeam *next;
    struct nodeTeam *prev;
}NodeTeam;
```

So I replace the `printf` by `addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq);`

```
fgets(buffer, 100, equipas)!= NULL);
eq.name= strtok(buffer,";\n");
eq.teamPlace= strtok (NULL,";\n");

addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq);
```

Now, if I print my linked list, I can see that my node is added but `name` and `teamPlace` contains rubbish characters. But if I do this:

```
fgets(buffer, 100, equipas)!= NULL);
eq.name= "test";
eq.teamPlace= "test2";

addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq);
```

I can see that all is working as expected so that leads me to thinking that the problem is when string the `char` on my `struct`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fgets(buffer, 100, equipas)!= NULL);` what?

Comment: @FatalError, ironic that your name appears after the "what?", considering your comment :)

Comment: Please post your code for addNodeTeamSorted and also for function that prints the list

Comment: Sorry. `fgets` is inside a `while` loop. Forgot to put it here. Followed `Attila` suggestions and made it work. If you still want the code here please ask but already marked my question as solved. Nevertheless many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` operates on the buffer you specify in [the first call](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/).  Instead of storing the returned pointers directly (which points back to `buffer`, that you overwrite in the processing of each line), you need to make a copy of the string (e.g. `strncpy()`)

Comment: I've done `strcpy(eq.name,strtok(buffer,";\n")); strcpy(eq.teamName,strtok(NULL,";\n")); printf("%s %s\n", eq.name,eq.teamPlace); addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq);` and can see that `printf` is showing what's is expected but after the call to `addNodeTeamsSorted(headEquipas,&tailEquipas,eq);` only the text of `eq.name` is printed as expected. `eq.teamPlace` is printing other thing

Comment: You need to allocate memory for `name` and `teamPlace` first, before you do the string copy (otherwise you are either writing to memory not owned by you, or overwriting other parts of the memory).  Also, at the minimum, use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` to prevent buffer overflow when the input is too large (`strcpy` does not check if there is enough space to do the copy)

Comment: Thanks. Followed your suggestion and made it work as expected. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your buffer is created on the stack, and strtok's results are pointing at the buffer.

When you return from this function, or read another line from the buffer, the stack (and therefore your buffer) is reused for something else, and the data your pointers are pointing to has been overwritten.  This doesn't happen with constant strings because they are in the static memory area and not on the stack.

Try using the function strdup() on the output of strtok() and save those into your structure; this will copy the strings returned by strtok() into the heap, where they won't be overwritten unexpectedly.